# Passing Integer Parameters to a C Program using the Command Line

Tags: c, scanf

Coming back to programming after a number of years, currently fiddling with a simple version of Euclid's algorithm. It currently works if I assign values to the integers within the program, so I'm assuming that the issue lies with how I'm passing the integers from the command line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Defining variables
int x,y, rem;

//Defining function gcd
int gcd(int x, int y);
//Where x>= y and y>=0

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Read in command line arguments
    x= sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &x);
    y= sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &y);

    gcd(x,y);
}

//Define recursive gcd function
int gcd(int x, int y)
{
    while(y !=0)
    {
        rem=x%y;
        x=y;
        y=rem;
        gcd(x,y);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: `man sscanf` will help you.

Comment: Don't tag with c++ if u mean c and vice versa

Comment: Apologies for the mis-tag.

Comment: Brief code review while we're here: I would have declared gcd() to be static so that its symbol doesn't get exported (unless you intend to export it) -- that's just a style thing; it keeps the namespace less cluttered and can help with debugging. Declaring x,y,rem to be global is unecessary, clutters the namespace, prevents recursion, makes the code thread-unsafe, and limits the optimizations the compiler can do. Better to declare x,y in the body of main() and rem in the body of gcd(). Finally, main() should return a value; I'm surprised that the compiler didn't squawk.

Comment: The call `gcd(x,y);` in `int gcd(int x, int y)` appears to serve no purpose.

Answer (score 8):

Along with it's sibling functions (printf, sprintf etc) `sscanf` returns the number of arguments correctly parsed - one in this case. You need to remove assignments of x and y to `sscanf`.

```
sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &x);
sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &y);
```

Comment: Thanks suspectus, but I had originally tried that.

Perhaps it's an issue with how I'm inputting the command line arguments. I will have a fiddle.

Comment: Sam - works for me after adding a printf to output the gcd result.

Comment: Ah! I was being dim and expecting the return function to print it for me. Has been a long time, sorry. Thank-you for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to avoid using sscanf() altogether. The functions atoi(), atof(), and atol() are standard C library functions specifically designed to convert strings into numerical values. For instance, the prototype for atoi(), "ascii to integer", is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int atoi(const char *str);
```

this should work for your code:

```
x = atoi(argv[1]);
```

etc.

Just remember to `# include` the stdlib.h header at the beginning of your program.

Here is a link to a decent reference for the standard C library: http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.13.html#atoi

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be assigning `x` and `y` the return value of `sscanf`, which means that after it has read the input and stored the values to the appropriate variables, you are then overwriting them. Try removing `x=` and `y=` from those lines.